# Compare two strings ignoring new line characters and white spaces

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to compare two strings ignoring whitespaces and newline characters, so the following strings should be equal:

```
"Initial directory structure.\r\n    \r\n    The directory tree has been changed"
"Initial directory structure.\n\nThe directory tree has been changed"
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Check out the most upvoted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718965/c-sharp-string-comparison-ignoring-spaces-carriage-return-or-line-breaks) question

Comment: Couldn't you just remove new line and whitespace characters out of both and compare?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859255/how-do-i-make-my-string-compare-not-sensitive-to-ignore-miner-differences-in-w/6859344#6859344

Comment: I gave an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41408399/24874

Answer (score 15, accepted):

how about:

```
string stringOne = "ThE    OlYmpics 2012!";
string stringTwo = "THe\r\n        OlympiCs 2012!";

string fixedStringOne = Regex.Replace(stringOne, @"\s+", String.Empty);
string fixedStringTwo = Regex.Replace(stringTwo, @"\s+", String.Empty);

bool isEqual = String.Equals(fixedStringOne, fixedStringTwo,
                              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(isEqual);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Do newlines count as whitespace?

Answer (score 10):

An alternative approach is to use the CompareOptions of String.Compare.

CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols

Indicates that the string comparison must ignore symbols, such as white-space characters, punctuation, currency symbols, the percent sign, mathematical symbols, the ampersand, and so on.

```
String.Compare("foo\r\n   ", "foo", CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(lhs, rhs, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) `

Answer (score 2):

copy the string then

```
xyz.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
xyz.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
string compareA = a.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "");
string compareB = b.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "");
```

Then you can compare both.

Maybe throw that in to a helper function:

```
public bool SpacelessCompare(string a, string b){
    string compareA = a.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "");
    string compareB = b.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "");

    return compareA == compareB;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind when you get rid of spaces these two strings are marked as being the same: `"The red over" "There dover"`

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = myString.Replace("", "Initial directory structure.\r\n    \r\n    The directory tree has been changed");
```

Now just check if they are equal.

```
String.Compare(myString, "Initial directory structure.The directory tree has been changed")
```

Comment: The first line makes no sense.