# How to compare strings by ignore " " prefix and postfix without call string.Trim()

Tags: c#, string, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String.comparison performance (with trim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862314/string-comparison-performance-with-trim)

I would like to write a function to judge whether two strings are equal or not, by ignore the first string's whiteSpace prefix and postfix, without call string.Trim(). 
Please also considering the insensitive case.

Suppose:

```
string str1 = "   Abc   ";
string str2 = "abc";

bool trueEqual = IsEqualWithoutWhiteSpace(str1, str2, /*ignore case?*/ true);  // return true.
```

Comment: "without call string.Trim()" why?

Comment: There is a reason `Trim` was written. *This is it.*

Comment: Why you have marked question with perfromance tag? Is it important and you are going to use this method on large strings?

Comment: I love that this is tagged "performance"  This is textbook early-optimization.

Comment: Have you done any performance testing to indicate that `strimg.Trim()` is too slow for your needs?

Comment: For some reason, i think this is some kind of homework question or maybe for a job interview.

Comment: Guys, let's not treat the OP like a child. Likely, he has a reason why his code must go fast. "Premature optimization" has become the standard answer for such questions, and it is not helpful.

Comment: @usr: Well, he asks like a child, ignoring the first two [How-To-Ask rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) of StackOverflow: "Do your homework" (i.e. *What have you tried? Where are you stuck?*) and "Be specific" (*Why do you think Trim is harmful to your solution?*).

Comment: Each call string.Trim() will create an new temp string, in our application, there is huge string (e.g. 50,000 records), and the function called frequently. I try to see whether this is a way can optimize it without call string.Trim().

Comment: @user: sorry if my question not clear to you. Will pay more attention next time. I'm not a child, actually i have a child:).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do this for performance reasons (this would be a valid reason in some cases - I'll spare you the usual premature optimization warnings).

First, count the number of whitespace chars in both strings at the beginning and at the end. If the non-whitespace portion is not of the same length, return false. Now we know it has the same length.

Next, call `stringA.IndexOf(stringB, ...)` with the appropriate start and count arguments to determine if a match was found. If there was a match, the string are equal according to your implementation.

If you don't need case-insensitivity you can use a loop to compare the middle part of both strings, too.

Comment: Yes, i concern about the performance, due to each call string.Trim() will create a new string. Not sure if i'm right to call it to deal with huge strings.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments show, there is no direct reason to not use trim. So if you are convinced that Trim is fine, here is a solution how to do it.

```
public static bool IsEqualWithoutWhiteSpace(this string aLhs, string aRhs)
{
    var left = aLhs.Trim();
    var right = aRhs.Trim();
    return left.Equals(right, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

string str1 = "   Abc   ";
string str2 = "abc";

var b = str1.IsEqualWithoutWhiteSpace(str2);
```

if it is a performance reason, please reconsider your question because you are asking "Can somebody write a function for me" instead of "Can somebody explain why my code is not working".

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is an extension of the "premature optimization" warnings given in the comments. You don't add anything to them.

Comment: @usr Sorry i intended to answer the initial question  "How to compare strings by ignore “ ” prefix and postfix without call string.Trim()" while taking the comments into account, that there is currently no reason to not use trim, without further informations from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

look ma, no `Trim()`!

```
        string str1 = "      AbC   ";
        string str2 = "abc";

        var r = new Regex("^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$");
        var trimStr1 = r.Replace(str1, "");
        var trimStr2 = r.Replace(str2, "");

        return trimStr1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Although, like everybody else is saying, I would use certainly use `Trim()` for this in one of my own projects.

Comment: No trim, and it's only magnitudes (approx.) slower (and doesn't work with most whitespace characters, like carriage return, line feed and so on... there's a reason why `\s` was invented for regexes)...^^

Comment: In my rough tests, it takes about 20 times as long using regex. So like I said, I'd just use `Trim()`.

Comment: paul, thanks for your help. Just as you said, the regex's performance is not good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

To kick the can once more Trim is your friend. However, another method to avoid using trim would be something like:

bool found = string1.Contains(string2);

If you are sure that string1 is the one that potentially has the whitespace and want to be case sensitive. If you don't want to be case sensitive throw in a .ToLower after each string:

bool found = string1.ToLower().Contains(string2.ToLower());

Finally if you aren't sure which one has the white space but only one of them will (ex. one of two inputs will come from a reasonably reliable source (like a string in code) and the other from something a user added but you aren't sure which order a user of your code might chose to put inputs in) you can use the or operator:

bool found = string1.Contains(string2) || string2.Contains(string1);

These are kind of special cases though and the .Net team does a pretty good job making their code efficient so it is likely calling trim and comparing once is more efficient than comparing twice and avoiding the Trim call (comparisons have to look at at least Len2 - Len1 number of combinations where as a trim can terminate once it finds a non-whitespace character so it is logically a simpler problem for the function call to solve.